# Why train NumPy array size is smaller than the whole dataset?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, image-processing

[image: shape]

I converted all the images, with the size of 100 x 100, into a numpy array and save it into a text file. After loading it and performing train_test_split, they're stored into X_train and X_test respectively. However, the shape become (75,100). Shouldn't it be (100,100)? Sorry,I'm new to machine learning

Comment: The first parameter is number of samples you have, like rows of data.  If you have 322 images in your training set, your shape should be `(322, 100, 100)` for black and white or grayscale images, and `(322, 100, 100, 3)` for color.  So it looks like something has gone wrong.

Comment: @James After defining the path to my image and store it into Z. I use this command ' img = np.array(Z) ' to convert the image into numpy array. Is it wrong??

Comment: You should ask this as a new question.  Are you opening and reading the file as binary data into Z, or reading it via an image library such as PIL?  The later is the correct way to do it.

Comment: I import Image from PIL to do so before I convert those images into a numpy array. But why is it still wrong??

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is hard to say

Answer (score 2):

If you have N images with size 100 X 100, you should pass an array with size (N, 100, 100). The function splits by first dimension. So, if you pass a single array with size 100x100, it thinks that each row of your picture is a training pattern and keeps 3/4 of the image as training set.

Comment: I understand that it'll be split into that ratio but I never expect it to be percentile. Shouldn't it be something like (70, 94) as I stored 94 images in the text file?? (94*75)/100 = 70.5 so assume that it's 70 or 71